# Preventing syntax highlighting in the wrap-prefix

Tags: org-mode, font-lock, syntax-highlighting, display, wrapping

When Emacs wraps long lines, is there a way to prevent the wrap prefix from having syntax highlighting (font-lock) or any such special properties?

Specifically, I have the following settings:

```el
;; Wrap long lines instead of having them truncated and fall off the screen
(setq truncate-lines nil)
;; Make wrapped lines start at half the available text width
(setq wrap-prefix '(space . (:width (0.5 . text))))
```

Now, long lines appear like (in `org-mode`):

[image: output]

Or with `visual-line-mode`:

[image: with visual-line-mode]

(No change with `adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode` turned on or off.)

Is there a way to have the wrapped line not retain the highlighting (the underline in the images above)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a stretch-glyph?

```lisp
(setq truncate-lines nil
      wrap-prefix (propertize (char-to-string ?\uE000)
                    'display '(space . (:width (0.5 . text)))))
```

With this, the examples in the question now look like:

[image: without visual-line-mode]

and with `visual-line-mode`:

[image]